# XML to Dataframe

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

Does anyone know how to convert following XML into R dataframe?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Body>
       <getCampaignsResponse>
                <getCampaignsResult>
                    <campaign>
                        <categoryBids>
                                <categoryBid>
                                    <campaignCategoryUID>1234</campaignCategoryUID>
                                    <campaignID>1211</campaignID>
                                    <categoryID>1254</categoryID>
                                    <selected>true</selected>
                                    <bidInformation>
                                      <biddingStrategy>Cpc</biddingStrategy>
                                      <cpcBid>
                                        <cpc>0.5</cpc>
                                      </cpcBid>
                                      <cpaBid xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    </bidInformation>
                                </categoryBid>
                                <categoryBid>
                                      <campaignCategoryUID>5487</campaignCategoryUID>
                                      <campaignID>3244</campaignID>
                                      <categoryID>1234</categoryID>
                                      <selected>true</selected>
                                      <bidInformation>
                                        <biddingStrategy>Cpc</biddingStrategy>
                                        <cpcBid>
                                          <cpc>0.2</cpc>
                                        </cpcBid>
                                        <cpaBid xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    </bidInformation>
                                </categoryBid>
                      </categoryBids>
                  </campaign>
              </getCampaignsResult>
          </getCampaignsResponse>
      </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

The class of the XML Object is:

```
> str(data)  
Classes 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>
```

The dataframe should have following columns:
campaignCategoryUID
campaignID
categoryID
biddingStrategy
cpc

With `xmlToDataFrame` or `xmlToList` I couldn´t achieve useful results. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the nodes by hand with something like `xpathSApply` and probably need to change the way you parse the response since it doesn't have any namespace definitions:

```
library(XML)

xml <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Body>
       <getCampaignsResponse>
                <getCampaignsResult>
                    <campaign>
                        <categoryBids>
                                <categoryBid>
                                    <campaignCategoryUID>1234</campaignCategoryUID>
                                    <campaignID>1211</campaignID>
                                    <categoryID>1254</categoryID>
                                    <selected>true</selected>
                                    <bidInformation>
                                      <biddingStrategy>Cpc</biddingStrategy>
                                      <cpcBid>
                                        <cpc>0.5</cpc>
                                      </cpcBid>
                                      <cpaBid xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    </bidInformation>
                                </categoryBid>
                                <categoryBid>
                                      <campaignCategoryUID>5487</campaignCategoryUID>
                                      <campaignID>3244</campaignID>
                                      <categoryID>1234</categoryID>
                                      <selected>true</selected>
                                      <bidInformation>
                                        <biddingStrategy>Cpc</biddingStrategy>
                                        <cpcBid>
                                          <cpc>0.2</cpc>
                                        </cpcBid>
                                        <cpaBid xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    </bidInformation>
                                </categoryBid>
                      </categoryBids>
                  </campaign>
              </getCampaignsResult>
          </getCampaignsResponse>
      </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>'

doc <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(xml, useInternalNodes = TRUE))

data <- data.frame(campaignCategoryUID=xpathSApply(doc, "//campaignCategoryUID", xmlValue),
                   campaignID=xpathSApply(doc, "//campaignID", xmlValue),
                   categoryID=xpathSApply(doc, "//categoryID", xmlValue),
                   biddingStrategy=xpathSApply(doc, "//biddingStrategy", xmlValue),
                   cpc=xpathSApply(doc, "//cpc", xmlValue))

data

##   campaignCategoryUID campaignID categoryID biddingStrategy cpc
## 1                1234       1211       1254             Cpc 0.5
## 2                5487       3244       1234             Cpc 0.2
```

You can also do the extraction functionally:

```
nodes <- c("campaignCategoryUID", "campaignID", "categoryID", "biddingStrategy", "cpc")
data <- rbind.data.frame(sapply(nodes, function(x) xpathSApply(doc, sprintf("//%s", x), xmlValue)))
```

provided you don't need to deal with edge cases (i.e. provided all the extractions are uniform and won't have "errors").

Comment: Thank you! Your solution woks fine for me!